# How do I implement OpenID in my web application?

Tags: web-applications, openid

Does Stackoverflow create a new OpenID when a user registers with an email address (i.e. does not provide an existing OpenID)?  How do you do that?  Do you have code examples in C#?  Java?  Python?

Answer (score 13):

You can find OpenID implementations [here](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries). If you just want more information, I would check out the [OpenID site](http://openid.net/).

Answer (score 7):

The [Plaxo OpenID recipe](http://archive.is/lQekQ) (from the [OpenID](http://openid.net/) site) was one of the better howtos I've seen.

Comment: Link down, I repeat, link down.

Comment: Not sure how out of date that recipe is but I've updated the link to the Web Archive of it.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman posted a while back about [setting up OpenID in .net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mis-understanding OpenID, the process of registering and OpenID is the responsibility of the user, you'll note that there is no place to signup here without an OpenID.