# Looking for a PHP based user management system

Tags: php, user-management

I am presently looking for a user management system in PHP which can easily be integrated and built on. I have googled for it and i have two or three already on the list to try out, but then again i want the benefit of personal recommendation based on usage and experience with a solution.

So if you know of any that has worked for you in time past, i would really appreciate if you can recommend.

Thanks!

Comment: clarify what your system will do. can you give any examples.. that will help us.

Comment: just want an identity system...something that would take care of creating new accounts, authenticating users and deal with things like password recovery etc.

Comment: Also, which one's are on your list? Maybe we can comment on those...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to don't that stuff yourself. Provide integration to systems like(to name a few):

- [openid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459509/how-to-use-open-id-as-login-system/4460342#4460342)
- [facebook connect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web)
- [twitter sign-in](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter)
- [rpxnow](https://rpxnow.com/)

There are libraries in almost any programming language(PHP), they are the most safe and users don't have to create (**ANOTHER**) separate account(etc).

Don't fall victim to security breach like for example l[ifehacker.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html) did. Like Jeff Atwood mentions security is hard and you should let the experts figure it out!

Comment: rpxnow has changed its name to Janrain Engage, i just noticed it on their website.

Comment: @Jorge that's true, but rpxnow.com still(always) works and engage.com does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but Ionisis.com provides a user management system among other things.  http://uams.ionisis.com/

Hope that helped.