# Getting Spammed Email after using Captcha

Tags: php, email, spam

I have used securimage captcha for a contact form but though I am getting spammed emails.
What is the procedure of protecting spammmed mail.

---

**Edit 1:**

I've got an idea that If I can check the email address is exist or not It may help me to protect spam.

Am I Correct?

Comment: You can try http://akismet.com/development/api/ which is used in Wordpress or google Recaptcha.

Comment: spammers use different email ids

Answer (score 0):

use some standard captcha techniques like http://www.google.com/recaptcha. Also read [Php: Check if email content is spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702397/php-check-if-email-content-is-spam)

Answer (score 0):

Use SMTP mail for contact us form. this will protect your mail goes to Spam folder .

Comment: if you are using php then you can use phpmailer http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/