# About php classes and my sql problem

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks. I would like to let user login , And i try to do it in oop way

Here is the loginPage.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php require_once("connection.php");
$instance=new connection("527442_1","chi1234a","foodil_zxq_1");
if (isset($_POST['s'])) {
    $SecIns=new login($_POST['u'],$_POST['p']);
    echo $SecIns->enter();
}
?>
<form name="fm" method="POST" action="show.php">
User Name :<input type="text" name="u">
<br>
Password: <input type="password" name="p">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="s">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the oop code which i fail `Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource`

```
<?php

class connection
{var $user;
var $pass;
var $db;

function __construct($user,$pass,$db){
$this->user=$user;
$this->pass=$pass;
$this->db=$db;
}

function conn(){
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost' , $this->user , $this->pass) or die ("Can't connect server");
mysql_select_db($this->db,$conn) or die ("DB error");
}
}

class login extends connection
{

function __construct($id,$pwd)
{$this->id=$id;
$this->pwd=$pwd;
}

function enter()
{$this->query="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='".$this->id."' AND pwd='". $this->pwd."';";
$result=mysql_query($this->query,$this->conn) or die ("Error:" . mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($this->result)<1)
return "Not correct user";
else
return "Login success";
}
}
?>
```

The problem is at the `function enter()` .Should be the format problem?? But i spend  a long time on it . Thanks.

Comment: 1. `var` and omitting the the visibility modificators (`public`, `protected`, `private`) is PHP4-style. You should learn how to write code in PHP5. 2. `mysql` is outdated for a while and will be marked as deprecated soon. You should use `MYSQLi`, or `PDO` instead. 3. You should _never_ access any `$_POST`-value directly without validating (same for `$_GET` and such).

Comment: it still not work, pls look at my code after modified

Comment: This wasn't an answer, that was just a comment about what you should clean up. Did you read the answers below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's commendable that you want to add organization to your code, adding the methods into a class doesn't automatically make it OOP. I recommend you read up on the basics and then reorganize your classes.

As for your problem,

```
$result=mysql_query('$this->query','$this->conn') or die( ..
--------------------------^
```

Those variables you passed are treated as literal strings because you've quoted them. you need to pass it an actual query and a connection object. Just remove the quotes.

Also, I recommend you look into parametrized queries : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

**EDIT**

Looking at your code further, these tips might improve your code

- Use upper case names for your classes. This makes them easier to read.
- You're correct in moving your connection to a different class, but your usage is wrong.
- Even though you've extended your Login class from your Connection class, you don't instantiate a connection object for use inside your Login class even though you refer to it in your code (e.g. - $this->conn)
- Instantiate your connection and pass it as a parameter for your other classes. Don't extend them from the connection.

  $conn = new Connection($username, $pass, $host, $db);
  $login = new Login($conn);
  $login->doLogin($username, $password);

And have a `query()` method in your connection, so you can call that method from your other classes.

Comment: $login = new Login($conn); ?? I already have a construtor to assign the user input id and password

Comment: So, if i use $login = new Login($conn); how to modify the constructor??thanks

Comment: Either have a method to set the connection, or pass it in with the other parameters. Whatever you choose, standardize it for all of your classes.

Comment: sorry but i don't get it. How to pass the connection string?

Comment: To be precise, how to modify in class LOGIN??

Comment: Missing argument 2 for connection::__construct()

Comment: Missing argument 3 for connection::__construct()

Comment: Have a look at this question, it goes into detail about this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707053/php-user-class-login-logout-signup

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query('$this->query','$this->conn') or die ("Error:" . mysql_error());
```

This piece of code does not evaluate to PHP stored variables. If you single-quote something, PHP won't attempt to parse it as if it was a variable. Remove the quotes.

After you do that, your code will fail at `connection::conn()` since there is no function `mysql_conn`. There is `mysql_connect`. And it takes arguments in different order (server is first for example, not 3rd argument).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{$query="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='".$this->id."' AND '".$this->pwd".';";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed something ; i write collectively from all answers

1  - `mysql_conn()` is not a function you have written in `function conn() {}`
 2  - remove `'` from `$result = mysql_query('$this->query','$this->conn')`
 3  -  you have missed one parameter in mysql statement

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='$this->id' AND        '$this->pwd';";
                                                         ^ (here)
```

4 - assign the query in `$this->query` instead of just `$query`

Answer (score 0):

you did not passed the connection object to the login object , thats why you have this error :  Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource . from where the login object is calling the $db , you are using resources in the login class without initiating them ... they are not exist until you set them .