# Is it ok to have an object without attributes?

Tags: php, oop, object, methods, attributes

I'm doing this software in PHP for my final school work and i must use OOP. I have this class "user" and it doesn't have any attributes in it, just methods(things the user can do like: register, post and background actions like encrypting it's password). I want to know if this is ok or not, the code works and all but i want to make sure i'm using OOP in PHP well.
 My class looks like this:

```
class user{
    function cryptPass($input){code}
    function regist_user($name,$email,$gender,$dob,$password){code}
    --more methods--
  }
```

Should i keep doing this or is it mandatory to have attributes up there for the user?

Comment: This usually indicates you don't need an object to do this and may be over complicating your code

Comment: My goal here was to put everything that my user can do in one place so i just call it whenever the user needs to perform the action. This way i won't have a lot of php code on every page, it's all in one place and well organized. I think that will save some time when debugging.

Comment: You shouldn't need classes to organize unrelated pieces of code. Good namspacing, etc, should do that for you.

Comment: You can use class without any attributes if you don't need any.

Comment: I haven't used namespacing yet.I think the code is related, isn't it?

Comment: This was worrying me because i'm doing a class diagram for the first time and i don't have any attributes to put there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a class if it doesn't have any attributes. You're using a class just to group a bunch of functions together. A class is used as a data structure to represents objects, like a real user with a name, a password, etc. Here, you just have utilities function which store nothing in memory.

A real `user` class should be [like in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707053/php-user-class-login-logout-signup).

What you need is to use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), to organize your application.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i need to do. I'll take these:$name,$email,$gender,$dob,$password and define them as attributes and change their values when the user registers using the regist_user() function. Right?

Comment: You doesn't need to make a project full OOP, it's heavier and not practical.

Comment: So do it if it's required, but it's not the best solution. It's syntactically correct but it's not the philosophy of the OOP.

Comment: I hope i use it better on other objects i have. I only have 2 weeks left so i don't want to get into a lot of details but since i'll still use the software after all this, i'll surely review the code.

Answer (score 1):

First you decide what type of object it is going to be. (**State-full or Stateless**)

State full objects supposed to have attributes to represents the state. But stateless objects can have only thread safe subroutines which performs some operations based on given parameters.