# checking password format

Tags: php

how to check user enterd password format. string not duplicate and use user must be choose numbers , strings (lowercase/uppercase)

hear is my code. whats my problem in preg_match?

```
function checkPassFormat($ip)
{
    if(preg_match('/^[a-A][0-9]/', $password))
        return TRUE;
    else 
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be telling us what the problem is and we tell you the solution?

Comment: this is a often asked question, did you check other questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796681/validate-password-with-preg-match-in-php e.g.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a cute solution for the issue (you can also collect the errors and show the user a friendly message):

```
const SECURELEVEL_LOW = 1;
const SECURELEVEL_MEDIUM = 2;
const SECURELEVEL_HIGH = 3;
const SECURELEVEL_SERVICE = 4;

const CONTAINS_LETTERS = 1;
const CONTAINS_DIGITS = 2;
const CONTAINS_CASESENSITIVELETTERS = 4;
const CONTAINS_SPECIALCHARS = 8;

public function _isValid($value) {
    $valid = true;
    switch ($this->_options['secureLevel']) {
      case self::SECURELEVEL_SERVICE:
        $minLength = 20;
        $hasToContain = self::CONTAINS_LETTERS + self::CONTAINS_DIGITS + self::CONTAINS_CASESENSITIVELETTERS + self::CONTAINS_SPECIALCHARS;
        break;
      case self::SECURELEVEL_HIGH:
        $minLength = 8;
        $hasToContain = self::CONTAINS_LETTERS + self::CONTAINS_DIGITS + self::CONTAINS_CASESENSITIVELETTERS;
        break;
      case self::SECURELEVEL_LOW:
        $minLength = 4;
        $hasToContain = 0;
        break;
      case self::SECURELEVEL_MEDIUM:
      default:
        $minLength = 5;
        $hasToContain = self::CONTAINS_LETTERS + self::CONTAINS_DIGITS;
        break;
    }

    if (strlen($value) < $minLength) {
      $valid = false;
    }
    if (strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
      $valid = false;
    }


    if ($hasToContain & self::CONTAINS_LETTERS) {
      // Password has to contain letters
      if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $value)) {
        $valid = false;
      }
    }

    if ($hasToContain & self::CONTAINS_DIGITS) {
      // Password has to contain numbers
      if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $value)) {
        $valid = false;
      }
    }

    if ($hasToContain & self::CONTAINS_CASESENSITIVELETTERS) {
      // Password has to contain small and capital letters
      if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $value) || !preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $value)) {
        $valid = false;
      }
    }

    if ($hasToContain & self::CONTAINS_SPECIALCHARS) {
      // Password has to contain a special character
      if (!preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', $value)) {
        $valid = false;
      }
    }

    return $valid;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `[a-A]` means that you're only allowing small and capital `A`. This should probably be `[a-zA-Z]`. You could also try `[a-Z]`, but in C# for example this doesn't work as expected.

Also you probably need to say "*more than one* letter followed by *more than one* number": `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+`. That would allow for passwords like `abDCkl98`.

If you want to mix letters and numbers, you should do something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. This is for passwords like `a9Bdc4re`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $password)
```

Comment: @Steve this definitely matches `a2`, well on PHP 5.4 is does.

Comment: it also matches "a" but - on which security level is a password with a string length of 1

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, here's another option:

```
"/[:alpha:][:digit:]/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try out this
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/i";
if(preg_match($pattern, $value)){           
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: If you add `i`, you don't need `A-Z` as then comparison is case insensitive.