# php cookies and session variables and ip address

Tags: php, session, variables, cookies

I posted a similar question before, but never really got an answer that helped me, so I'm looking to try again. As a disclaimer, I know that a lot of the information in here doesn't follow perfect coding practices, but it is for exercise purposes only. I've tried a million things and nothing seems to be working because I'm not really sure where everything should go! I desperately need some (any!) help so thanks in advance if you can offer anything!

I'm trying to create a simple form / page that uses some basic cookie and session stuff to produce some user-specific data. I was moving along good until I came across a few problems that I can’t figure out. On my first page everything is good except for I just want the NAME of the browser the user is using. (for example, I want just the simple title: Firefox instead of the whole long version of the browser.) I've seen this be done so I think it’s possible, I just don’t know how to do it!

My real problems come up right about here, because I'm not exactly sure how to store the IP address, browser info and the current date/time (which I want shown on page 2) as session variables. Tried a few things I found, but I don’t think I was doing it right.

I also worked endlessly on trying to store the username and passwords as two separate cookies each...suggestions? Finally, what do I need to do to have a location header (used to call form_data.php) with output buffering?

(Not sure this will be that helpful, considering I probably did everything wrong! LOL) This is a totally stripped-down version of my code. Tried to post my cleanest version, even though it doesn't have much info, so that you could easily see what I was trying to do.

main file code:

```
<?php 
header('Location: form_data.php'); 


 setcookie('username', $_POST['username']); 
 setcookie('password', $_POST['password']); 
 //I know this isn't working.   
 //honestly I just left this in here as to show where I had been 
 //trying to save the cookie data. Pretty obvious how bad my 
 //trial and error with this went! 

 } 
?> 


<?php 

 $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
echo " By the way, your IP address is: </b>".$_SESSION['ip']."<br />"; 
 echo " You already know this, but the browser you are currently using 
 to view this page is:<br/>";  //What is the correct function that I should be using here? 
 echo "<form action=\"form_data.php\" method=\"post\">"; 
 echo "username:<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"20\" value=\"\"><br/>"; 
 echo "password:<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"20\" value=\"\"><br/>"; 
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit, please\" />"; 
 echo "<br /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submitted\" value=\"true\" />"; 
 ?>
```

form_data.php

```
  <?php 

   echo "Hello, ".$username;//I'm trying to get the cookie data for the username 
   echo "Your password is ".$password; //Samething here (want cookie data) 
   echo "The date and time you entered this form is: ".date("F j, Y")." -- ".date("g:i a"); 
   echo "<br/>Your IP:".$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
   echo "<br/>Your broswer:".;//I want full broswer data here...dont know how to do it. 
   //Overall, was this the way to get the session variables for IP, date/time and browser? 
   echo  "Thank you for filling out this form!"; 
   ?>
```

Comment: Do NOT store your username and password in cookies! Instead store some random string in the cookie to allow the user to return later by matching a value in the database to the cookie value, and regenerate that value on every page load.

Comment: Don't use `setcookie`, ever. Just always use `$_SESSION` and maintain all the data that's relevant to the session on the server. The only cookie that the client will need is the session cookie, and you don't have to handle that explicitly (apart from regenerating it once upon successful login to avert fixation).

Comment: @Kerrek SB Cookies are still useful to persist non-sensitive information beyond the life of the server's session.  They serve a different purpose than `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 5):

To get the browser, use the [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.get-browser.php) function:

```
$browserinfo = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$browsername = $browserinfo['browser'];
```

Your session and cookie storage will never work because you are making a `header("Location");` call before attempting to set cookies.  You cannot send any output before setting cookies or establishing a session.

Before any output to the screen, call `session_start()`;

```
// attach to your session (or create if it doesn't exist)
// You must call session_start() on every page where you intend to access or set session vars
// and it must be called before any output (including whitespace at the top)
session_start();

// Store some stuff...
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Store user info in session, not cookie
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

// Set a cookie
// Not a super secure token, but better than user/pass in cookies.
// Point here is just to show that it must be done before any output or before the redirection header.
$_SESSION['token'] = sha1(time() . rand() . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie('token', $_SESSION['token']);
// In practice, you'd want to store this token in a database with the username so it's persistent.

// Now do the redirection:
// Supposed to be an absolute URL by the HTTP spec
header("Location: http://example.com/form_data.php");

// exit right after the redirection to prevent further processing.
exit();
```

---

**ADDENDUM after comments**

While you work, make sure PHP displays all errors on screen.  Be sure to turn off `display_errors` when your code goes onto a live public server.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To retrieve values from cookies as you said in your question you didn't know how to do, use the `$_COOKIE` superglobal:

```
// On the page that sets it...
setcookie('somename', 'somevalue', expiry, domain);

// On the page that retrieves it...
echo $_COOKIE['somename'];
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that! ... Looking at your code is a little overwhelming to me but I'm really trying to actually learn as I go (pretty new to PHP). So, do I need to totally scrap my first original code Or should I add the elements you have presented into my file? I find that when I try and combine even some of my own codes I get into trouble and everything stops working... :(

Comment: @clk Try integrating my code into yours.  The important part to remember is to call `session_start()` at the top of each page.  Then you will have access to anything you stored there via `$_SESSION`. Make sure you've turned on `display_errors` (see above) while you work so you can see what's failing and why.

Answer (score 4):

```
> I'm trying to create a simple form /
> page that uses some basic cookie and
> session stuff to produce some
> user-specific data.
```

Sessions do use [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) under the cover(only store [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) inside cookie/[set_cookie](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)) and I advice you to use only sessions because cookies can leak information(store all the information inside cookie on that user's computer) which could be dangerous while session uses the server's filesystem/database or whatever you like when you override [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

---

```
> On my first page everything is good
> except for I just want the NAME of the
> browser the user is using.
```

Like [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500654/php-cookies-and-session-variables-and-ip-address/6500727#6500727) said you can use [get_browser](https://www.php.net/manual/function.get-browser.php) for that:

> Attempts to determine the capabilities
> of the user's browser, by looking up
> the browser's information in the
> browscap.ini file.

Like the PHP page says it tries to determine and you should **NOT** rely on this information for anything important because it can be wrong(you can fool the system, if you like). What I mean is you should not use it to validate/proof something.

---

```
> My real problems come up right about
> here, because I’m not exactly sure how
> to store the IP address, browser info
> and the current date/time (which I
> want shown on page 2) as session
> variables.
```

More information to [retrieve the IP address](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html) can be read here(proxy-server could mislead you a little bit maybe?). To store that information just store it inside a session by first issuing `session_start()` on top of every page(before outputting anything) that wants to use sessions(only those to not set cookies on every page which makes page a little slower) and next store the current time inside a session variable by doing something along the lines of `$_SESSION['time'] = date(DATE_RFC822);`. You can read more about retrieving the time at [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) page.

So the code on `page 1` looks something like:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['ip'] = getRealIpAddr(); # no php function => See http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html
$_SESSION['time'] = date(DATE_RFC822);
```

Then on `page 2` you could retrieve this information using something like:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['ip']; // retrieve IP

> I also worked endlessly on trying to
> store the username and passwords as
> two separate cookies
> each...suggestions?
```

Don't store them inside a cookie(only using set_cookie and not using sessions to store information) but store them inside a session for extra security. But sessions are also vulnerable to [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) so after storing something critical inside your session you should [regenerate session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) **and never output/show** that information to the browser/user to prevent any leakage.

---

```
> Finally, what do I need to do to have
> a location header (used to call
> form_data.php) with output buffering?
```

Like Michael said you should be using [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function and [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) to terminate script after that

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

**P.S: Never store any really sensitive information like creditcard(use paypal or something) numbers or anything in your own database. I also advice you not to store passwords inside your database but use something like openId([Google's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459509/how-to-use-open-id-as-login-system/4460342#4460342)) for example to handle your authentication for extra security.**

Comment: As said in the comments of your link regarding `getRealIpAddr();`, spoofing the HTTP_CLIENT_IP or HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is trivial. And thus `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is more secure. Or keep track of all three values.. so you can force re-authentication on any change.