# How do I secure Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, security, node.js, socket.io

I've been working with Socket.IO for a few days and it's been both extremely exciting and even more frustrating. The lack of current documentation/tutorials has made learning it very difficult. I finally managed to create a basic chat system, but there is one glaring question. How do I secure it?

What's stopping a malicious user from copying (or editing) my code and connecting to my server? I can grab the username from my PHP script and submit it to Socket.IO so I can recognize them as that user (and the PHP has security of course), but what's stopping someone from just submitting an unregistered username?

How can I make sure that the events submitted are authentic and haven't been tampered with?

My basic socket.io chat for references.

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
var connectCounter = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
connectCounter++;
 console.log('People online: ', connectCounter);

socket.on('set username', function(username) {
socket.set('username', username, function() {
console.log('Connect', username);

    });
});
socket.on('emit_msg', function (msg) {
    // Get the variable 'username'

socket.get('username', function (err, username) {
      console.log('Chat message by', username);
      io.sockets.volatile.emit( 'broadcast_msg' , username + ': ' + msg );
    });

  });

socket.on('disconnect', function() { connectCounter--; });
});
```

Client:

```
    <?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id='message' type='text'>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://mysite.com/execs/login.php?login_check=true',
  dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
var username = data.username;
socket.emit('set username', username, function (data){
});

}
});

  socket.on('broadcast_msg', function (data) {
        console.log('Get broadcasted msg:', data);
        var msg = '<li>' + data + '</li>';
        $('#content').append(msg);
      });


$('#message').keydown(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
e.stopPropagation();
          var txt = $(this).val();
          $(this).val('');
          socket.emit('emit_msg', txt, function (data){
            console.log('Emit Broadcast msg', data);
          });
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It all works dandy, except for having absolutely no security.

Comment: A starting point -> https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Comment: to add to what @ManseUK said, you can then check in the callback if the provided username is also logged in. This is essential to prevent a chat only with someone who is actually logged in.

Comment: Another option would be to authenticate in PHP using Username / password then save a cookie - then within Node.js check the existence and content of the cookie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can install a key-value store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) on your node server, you can access it remotely from your php server using a Redis client like [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis/). All you have to do is updating the remote session store on node server when a new login/logout happens in your php server.

Check this post for details: [Authenticate user for socket.io/nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502031/authenticate-user-for-socket-io-nodejs)

Answer (score 3):

The excellent passport framework for express uses secure cookies to validate identity. There is even a [module](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) to access it from socket.io.