# How to secure a private socket.io room?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am wondering if this is the correct way to go about securing a socket.io room. Currently these are the steps that I am taking to ensure a user ends up in a private room, now I need to make sure the user gets authenticated before he is able to join.

1. A client connects to my `socket.io` server by calling `io.connect` and passing along the room he wants to join.
2. Client will be subscribed to the room and waits for emit of a message.
3. `socket_write` sends a `json_encoded` object to my server which holds a data property and the room to which this data will be sent.
4. My server receives the data through `socket.on` and emits the data to the given room where the client is listening.
5. The client will receive the proper information meant for him only.

**My client code:**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
   socket.emit('room', window.location.href);
});
```

**The server:**

```
const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    // The event that fires on PHP's socket_write.
    socket.on('data', (msg) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(msg);

        io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('log', data.html.toString().trim());
    });
}).listen(5600);
```

**The `on` connection event of my server:**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // A client will trigger this event and pass their window.location.href(room) as room identifier.
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });
});
```

**How I write to my socket.io server:**

```
$data = [
    'html' => 'test',
    'room' => 'http://app.dev/stephan-v/app-test'
];

$json = json_encode($data);

socket_write($this->socket, $json, strlen($json));
```

This is my implementation of a private websocket message but of course this is not secure. If somebody knows the name of the room that person could easily listen in on the emitted messages.

Since the `socket.join` can only take place on my server I guess the only place to authentication is at that point?

So instead of simply passing along the room I guess I should also pass in data to authenticate the user. And at that point make an AJAX requests from my `node` server to my `PHP` backend?

Obviously I do not want to send a plain password and username over the wire so I have been reading up on JSON web tokens. I guess you need to:

1. send a JWT to the `node` server at the point of connection(along with which room to join, which I am currently doing).
2. Make an AJAX requests from my `node.js` server to my `PHP` backend on an authentication route.
3. Only let the user join the room if that user gets authenticated.

Sorry for the long post but there are a lot of components involved in this so I am hoping someone could confirm this workflow and perhaps give me some tips/pointers.

I would prefer not to install something like Redis at the moment because although it is a nice bridge between the frontend/backend it feels like overkill right now and I would like to understand this all at a more basic level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I secure Socket.IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519777/how-do-i-secure-socket-io)

Comment: The main accepted answer there is to install Redis to deal with this, which feels like major overkill to me. I do not want to have yet another service and I do not currently need to scale this up. I am hoping to keep this basic and at the moment clear of dedicated packages. For simplicity and to learn how this all works exactly.

Comment: Sorry Steve. Since I didn't see that in your post, I have raised the flag.. You have edited it now though!. Thanks