# Implement Open Id login

Tags: php, openid

I am curious to know how can i add the Open ID login to my website, like the one this site (stackoverflow.com) is using.

My intention is to enable users to login into my site, without registration. So if they just have an account at popular sites like google, yahoo or facebook, they must be able to login to my website.

Can anyone suggest me a good and free solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stackoverflow here are answer

[How to use open id as login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459509/how-to-use-open-id-as-login-system)

[How do I implement OpenID in my web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407/how-do-i-implement-openid-in-my-web-application)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shakti singh, but i want the buttons like google, facebook, etc. on my site, upon clicking on them, it will connect to the authentication site. How can i do this?

Comment: Can anyone suggest me a solution? How can i put buttons of facebook and google login in my site? Or shall i tweak openinviter to authenticate the users?

Comment: I saw an example where i use a button with action set to a page like https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id  for Google login, using openid. Similarly, how can i do this for facebook and other sites ?

Comment: I found Lightopenid to be useful for atleast with Google, Yahoo and AOL. http://gitorious.org/lightopenid  And for facebook, iam using facebook connect.